# Why aren't my data being masked?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

```
data = [[0, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 6, 6],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 6, 6]]
```

The data object i have is a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Knowing data is a numpy object i did the following:

```
data = np.array(data)
```

i want to set the numbers inside a list i give as input to 0, what i tried:

```
data[~np.isin(data,[2,4])] = 0
```

i expect all the 2 and 4 occurrences in the previous matrix to be 0 and the rest to keep their values, what i got:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

also tried to give data as a numpy array using `np.array` gave error as well.

Comment: What's that magical `labels`?

Comment: Changed to `data` thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I well believe you'd get that error trying to use `data[~np.isin(data,[2,4])]` if data is a list, but I don't believe it would fail if data were an `ndarray`.  Please edit to include the full output of `data = [that stuff]`, `data = np.array(data)`, `data[~np.isin(data,[2,4])] = 0`, `print(data)`.  I mean, it'd give the opposite of what you wanted, but it shouldn't raise an error.

Comment: @DSM i checked the type of data in my code and it's a `<class numpy.ndarray>` but doing `data = np.array(data)` didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not negate the mask from [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) check if you intend to set those matching values to 0. The below code works just fine:

Also, you should make the `data` a numpy array instead of list of lists.

```
In [10]: data = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
    ...:         [1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 6, 6],
    ...:         [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 6, 6]])
    ...:         

In [11]: data[np.isin(data, [2, 4])] = 0

In [12]: data
Out[12]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 6, 6],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 6, 6]])
```

---

Just to reproduce your error:

```
In [13]: data = [[0, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
    ...:         [1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 6, 6],
    ...:         [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 6, 6]]
    ...:         

In [14]: data[np.isin(data, [2, 4])] = 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-06ee1662f1f2> in <module>()
----> 1 data[np.isin(data, [2, 4])] = 0

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: i just checked the type of data, it's `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` as in the example it's a variable and function of other previous calculations not just hardcoded as is, would this affect the answer by any means